# Ember compatible jQuery version

Tags: jquery, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am migrating my product purely build over jQuery-1.5.1.js to Ember.

I am new to ember and gradually picking up the pace.

My concern is whether I need to use jQuery 2.x version or I need to take the latest 1.x versions and why. I also need to use jQuery UI widgets to build all my components.

I need to support IE-9+ and above.

So can I go with jQuery 2.x version and make sure that I can have higher performance and all the features supported by Ember.

Used the following versions of Handlebars and Ember.

I do have any performance issues with jQuery versions.

handlebars-v1.3.0.js

ember-v1.5.1.js

Answer (score 1):

I saw your post on the Ember discussions forums first, but I'm going to go ahead and copy my answer here, since SO is generally more visible than the Ember forums.

> I've been using jQuery 2.0.3 with Ember 1.5 since it came out a little over two months ago. We've been using it in our soon-to-be production app since then and haven't had any issues. Since the 2.x branch supports IE9 and above, I'd recommend going with that. You'll save some space and get some tiny performance improvements over 1.x.